# Disposing declarative per-request data without using an HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, idisposable, httpcontext

I have a 'context' object that ties itself to HttpContext.Items via a static Current property. This object can be used directly, through expression builders and controls, all being part of the same library.

The issue I'm coming across is that I want to dispose of it's managed resources (WCF clients) when a request ends without using an HttpModule (since it is otherwise not needed). I have implemented the [full disposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) (with Finaliser), but you can't rely on the GC finalising instances in a timely manner.

I have tried to subscribe a static method to HttpApplication.EndRequest (also PostRequestHandlerExecute) in the objects constructor (with locking to ensure it only happens once), but the event is never dispatched. This is presumably because the instance of HttpApplication changes, though I'm not entirely sure.

Any thoughts on the best way to go about solving this?

Comment: No, it's a SOAP request. The question was more general, though.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing requests to a static event will cause a memory leak. It prevents the request from beging garage collected because it holds a reference to HttpApplication.

If you want to call dispose on an item cached in `HttpContext.Items` you need to do this at the end of the request. If you don't want to use a HttpModule use Global.ascx and hook the `EndRequest` event.

```
void Global_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var disposableItem = app.Context.Items["disposableItem"] as IDisposable;
    if (disposableItem != null)
    {
        disposableItem.Dispose();
    }
}
```